# Angular 4 e Nodejs Express - Problema com CORS

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, angular, cors

Olá, tenho duas aplicações que rodam localmente em portas diferentes. Uma aplicação é para API's e outra é a parte web.

Quando envio os dados do formulário para o meu service do typescript, está chegando corretamente os dados. Porém na controller da API, está chegando undefined. Pode ser problema de CORS? Coloquei setHeader e fiz alguns testes. Antes estava dando erro de permissão e agora foi resolvido. Porém, o problema do objeto undefined permanece.

A aplicação web vai para um service do typescript e esse service por sua vez, chama a API.

**Estou setando o header assim**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});
```

**Código do service**

```
  @Injectable()
  export class UserService {
   constructor(private http:Http) { }

   save(user: User) {
     let cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
     });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });
     this.http.post("http://localhost:4000/users", 
     user, options)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
        console.log("ddddd");
        });

        return user;
}
```

}

**E o código da API é esse:**

```
module.exports = class UserController {
 save(user){
    console.log('esse user vem undefined' + user)
    user.userName = user.email.split("@")[0];
    models.User.create(user)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('ok')
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

}

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isto

```
save(req, res ){
    const user = { user.userName: req.body.email};
    user.userName = user.email.split("@")[0];
    models.User.create(user)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('ok')
     })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```